# Ceiling fan wiring causing circuit breaker to trip

Tags: circuit-breaker, ceiling-fan

[image]My circuit breaker for the upstairs lights has tripped (circuit breaker popped and sparked). It looks like it might be due to our bedroom ceiling fan which was running at the time. There seem to be 3 live wires going into a chokblok and they look damaged. The chokblok was covered in electrical tape. What's the best way to wire this up? Should I just tape up the damaged wires and chokblok then try again?

the sparking was from the circuit breaker. There isn't enough of the damaged wires to cut them back, hence why I thought taping them might be best option. But I can look into how to use heat shrink tubing. Are you saying that the 3 live wires going into the chokblok is okay or is there a better option? What's the best way to isolate the wires? Thanks for your help
Cheersenter image description here

Comment: Why is one slot in the splice block badly blackened?  Was this wiring arrangement chosen by a qualified and trained person?

Comment: Where in the world are you located? That does not look like it's to code in the US, but may be perfectly legal and deemed safe in other countries.

Comment: Please consider [merging your unregistered and registered accounts](/help/merging-accounts), which will allow you to [edit](/help/privileges/create-posts), [comment on](/help/privileges/comment) any of your posts and most importantly [accept an answer](/help/someone-answers) on your question. Thanks, and welcome to the site!

Answer (score 1):

Properly wired, those terminal blocks have no need of (nor benefit from) wrapping in tape. Which suggests that improper wiring was performed.

If wiring insulation is actually damaged past the point where you can just cut out the damage, either the wire should be replaced, or something a bit more substantial such as heat shrink tubing should be used to repair it properly.

However, a probable first step would be to isolate the wires here and see  if the problem with the breaker is actualy solved, since you are (evidently) just guessing this might be the source (unless this was what "sparked" - your question reads as the breaker "popped and sparked;" if that's not correct, you should edit the question to clarify what, exactly, did those things.)